# Il y a-t-il un nom pour exprimer la tournure de phrase [pronom tonique] + infinitif ?

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot

Prenons la phrase  "Moi faire ça." Il y a-t-il une façon de nommer cette tournure ? J'ai trouvé "pidgin", est-ce une bonne façon de qualifier cette idée ?

Comment: [Pidgin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pidgin) c'est autre chose ... Il se peut que de telles expressions se disent en tel ou tel pidgin mais les deux concepts n'ont vraiment rien à voir.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Est-ce que ça pourrait être qualifié de pseudo-langage selon vous ; de déviance syntaxique ? Merci !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On entend régulièrement [*« petit-nègre »*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/n%C3%A8gre) pour nommer un français approximatif, à la syntaxe simplifiée et au vocabulaire limité.

Le mot *« nègre »* étant depuis longtemps déjà passé de mode et considéré comme péjoratif, l’expression, formée en 1877 selon *le Petit Robert*, semble véhiculer un relent de racisme et de condescendance qui ne sont plus très à leur place dans le monde d’aujourd’hui. Le *dictionnaire d’expressions et locutions* de la série *Les usuels* de Robert note d’ailleurs :

> Enfin, la locution dit en clair : « les Noirs parlent (donc pensent) comme des enfants. »

Ce qui s’interprète aisément comme une condamnation de l’expression.

Si maintenant, afin d’éviter cette disgracieuse expression, on recherche des synonymes, on ne retrouve malheureusement que la périphrase initiale *(français approximatif)*. Dans aucun des outils que j’ai consultés *(Robert des synonymes, Grand Druide des synonymes,* et le moteur de recherche *Google)* je n’ai trouvé de synonyme en un seul mot, ce qui est dommage, car il se pourrait que l’on assure de cette manière la pérennité de l’expression *« petit-nègre »*, que je puis certes nommer, mais assurément pas recommander.

---

En cherchant davantage et en acceptant des mots de sens quelque peu différent, on pourra citer :

• [BARAGOUIN](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/baragouin). Habituellement un langage peu compréhensible *(ce qui n’est pas le cas de **Moi faire ça**, cité en exemple dans la question)*, mais possiblement avec la nuance d’un langage de qualité inférieure, ce qui pourrait approcher ***Moi faire ça***.

• CHARABIA. Selon *le Petit Robert*, langage, style incompréhensible ou grossièrement incorrect. De nouveau, l’exemple est assez compréhensible, mais très sommairement formé.

• SABIR. Un système linguistique faisant appel au vocabulaire de plusieurs langues, mais à la syntaxe minimaliste. Un sabir est une langue surtout utilisée pour les échanges commerciaux entre peuples de langues très différentes. Par extension, une langue semée d’emprunts et difficile à comprendre par ceux qui n’y sont pas initiés. Le [chiac](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiac) pourrait être un exemple de cette extension de sens. On s’éloigne cependant un peu plus encore de la tournure dite *« petit-nègre »*, et il semble difficile de concilier la forme ***Moi faire ça***, qui ne possède que des mots français, à quelque définition de *sabir* que ce soit.